# DebugDiagnosticTool Rule for process which restart eriodically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, debugdiag

I suspect the memory leak in our ASP.NET MVC application. I would like create a `DebugDiagnosticTool` rule for memory leak. The rule is attached to the w3wp process. The problem is we use different process for each app pool. Additionally the app pool is recycled every day and newly created process has of course different PID. Is there any way to automatically create a rule after the IIS pool recycles?

Comment: Only the tougher cases need DebugDiag memory leak rule (such as memory leak from native side). Managed side issues can be easily identified from hang dumps by using a good enough memory profiler or WinDbg. Hire an experienced consultant or contact Microsoft support if you need more guidance.

Comment: Analyzing dump files is a complex process, I suggest you open a [support ticket](https://support.microsoft.com) for this, microsoft engineers will help analyse the dump file & try to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate the rule creation in IIS by navigate to DebugDiag path and use this syntax in PowerShell:

```
DebugDiag.Cmd.exe -rule -type Memory -name "Memory Leak Rule" -process w3wp.exe
```

Hope this answered your need.

Comment: It doesn't work.  Command executed in directory: C:\Program Files\DebugDiag Returned: "DebugDiag.Cmd.exe : The term 'DebugDiag.Cmd.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet," There is no DebugDiag.Cmd file in this directory.